# Is there a drupal function to jump out of the page rendering process and return a page not found?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I would like to have the choice in a variable_load function (as used to load variables from menu arguments) to circumvent the remainder of the page rendering process and give the user a "page not found."

I could use a drupal_goto() but I would prefer not to redirect the user and change the url in their browser.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could use [`drupal_not_found()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_not_found/6) to bring up the "page not found" message without altering the URL.